# echo {0..9} without space

Tags: echo

There is a space in between

```
$ echo {0..9}
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

How do I produce similar output using `echo {0..9}` without space?

Desired output

```
0123456789
```

Comment: `echo 0123456789`

Comment: `0-9` is just an example, what if you've up to `1000`? Still want to do it manually?

Comment: Why not? It's only 2895 bytes. But what would a line containing numbers not separated by spaces (`012...9989991000`) be good for?

Answer (score 10):

`seq` allows you to specify a separator using `-s`:

```
$ seq -s '' 0 9
012345678
```

Answer (score 10):

try:

```
echo -e \\b{0..9}
```

from [`man echo`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo):

```
-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
\b     backspace
```

or better to use [`printf`](/q/65803/72456):

```
printf '%s' {0..9}
```

or to add last newline:

```
printf '%s' {0..9} $'\n'
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the backspace is a byte on its own right and therefore should be avoided if this is going to be redirected to a file, for example. The Printf solution is cleaner in that regard.

Comment: @Quasímodo absolutely, yes.

Answer (score 5):

Use `tr` to remove the spaces:

```
$ echo {0..9} | tr -d ' '
```

`tr` man page:

```
       -d, --delete
              delete characters in SET1, do not translate
```

Answer (score 3):

For the record, note that `{0..9}` does come from `zsh` initially.

Like csh's `{a,b}` which it builds upon, it expands to separate arguments.

So for those to be bundled back together on output, you need a command that prints or can print its arguments joined with each other, like `printf`:

```
printf %s {0..9}
```

(though that doesn't print the terminating newline, see [αғsнιη's answer](/a/613467) to work around it)

Or have an extra step that does the joining.

In `zsh`, you can join elements of an array with nothing in between with `${(j[])array}`, so you could use an anonymous function like:

```
() { print ${(j[])@}; } {0..9}
```

or

```
function { print ${(j[])@}; } {0..9}
```

In Korn-like shells (including `bash` and `zsh`), to join elements of any array with nothing, you use `"${array[*]}"` whilst `$IFS` is empty:

```
set {0..9}
IFS=
echo "$*"
```

(here using `echo` instead of `print`, as though `bash` is a Korn-like shell even more so than zsh, it didn't implement the `print` builtin).

With `bash` or `zsh`, you can also do the joining into a variable with:

```
printf -v var %s {0..9}
```

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
echo $'\e[D'{0..9}
0123456789
```

In the terminal it looks solid but is actually connected by the separator out of the terminal control sequences.

```bsh
echo $'\e[D'{0..9} | cat -vet
^[[D0 ^[[D1 ^[[D2 ^[[D3 ^[[D4 ^[[D5 ^[[D6 ^[[D7 ^[[D8 ^[[D9$
```

`'\e[D'` - move cursor left
`echo $'string'` or `echo -e 'string'` - enable interpretation of backslash escapes.

Comment: Interesting. But trouble may occur for latter usage of the generated sequence.